# What is the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(A) $ with respect to $A $( unit tensor) and derivative of $A$ w.r.to $\operatorname{tr}(A) $

Tags: derivatives, tensors

$\boldsymbol A$ is a (symmetric) second order tensor.

In index notation, one can proof that

$\frac{\partial \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol A)}{\partial \boldsymbol A} =  \frac{\partial A_{ii}}{\partial A_{jk}} \boldsymbol e_j \otimes \boldsymbol e_k = \delta_{ij} \delta_{ik} \boldsymbol e_j \otimes \boldsymbol e_k = \delta_{jk} \boldsymbol e_j \otimes \boldsymbol e_k =\boldsymbol I$

Is it possible at all to compute

$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol A}{\partial \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol A)} $ ?

In index notation,

$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol A}{\partial \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol A)} = \frac{\partial A_{jk}}{\partial A_{ii} } \boldsymbol e_j \otimes \boldsymbol e_k = \dots = \boldsymbol I$ ,

the result would be the same.

However, the result does not make sense to me. If I, sloppy speaking, change the denominator $\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol A)$ by a small amount, why should all $A_{ii}$ change the same?

Comment: Wellcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you for pointing out!